# Adding specific amounts of WEEKDAY time to string

Tags: php

I'm looking to add a certain amount of time to a string, but skip the weekdays. So, for example if I wanted to add 40 hours to the timestamp `"2014-04-03 19:33:40"` it would return `"2014-04-07 11:33:40"` (having skipped the weekend).

I also need to do this with days and possibly minutes. Here is the (non-working) function I've come up with:

```
function expiration_date($opentime,$tfString)
{

    switch($tfString)
    {
        case "daily" :
            $expiration_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($opentime . ' + 10 weekdays'));
            break;

        case "4h":
            $expiration_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($opentime . ' + 40 weekday hours'));
            break;

        case "1h":
            $expiration_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($opentime . ' + 10 weekday hours'));
            break;

        case "30m":
            $expiration_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($opentime . ' + 5 weekday hours'));
            break;

        case "15m":
            $expiration_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($opentime . ' + 2.5 weekday hours'));
            break;

        default:        $expiration_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    }

    return $expiration_date;

}
```

Comment: Do business  hours matter?

Comment: nope, just weekdays/weekends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addRollover($opentime , $tfString) {
    switch($tfString) {
        case "daily" :
            $interval = 'P10D'; break;
        case "4h":
            $interval = 'PT40H'; break;
        case "1h":
            $interval = 'PT10H'; break;
        case "30m":
            $interval = 'PT5H'; break;
        case "15m":
            $interval = 'PT2H30M'; break;
        default:        
            return '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    }
    $interval = new DateInterval($interval);
    $datetime = new DateTime($opentime);
    $datetime->add($interval);

    if (in_array($datetime->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday'))) {
        $start = clone $datetime;
        if ('Sunday' === $datetime->format('l')) {
            $start->modify('previous Saturday');
        }
        $start->setTime(0, 0, 0);

        $diff = $start->diff($datetime); 
        $datetime->modify('next Monday'); 
        $datetime->add($diff);

        if ('daily' === $tfString) {
            $datetime->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
        }
    }
    else if ('daily' === $tfString) {
        $datetime->add(new DateInterval('P4D'));    
    }

    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

echo addRollOver('2014-04-03 19:33:40', '4h'); // 2014-04-07 11:33:40
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/esh29g)

What you see happening here:

1. We start by getting ther amount of time we need to add [as a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) we can pass to `DateInterval()`. If we can't find one we return a default time.
2. We create our `DateInterval()` object.
3. We create our `DateTime()` object representing our starting date and time.
4. We add our interval to our datetime.
5. If the resulting date and time is a weekend...
6. We find the difference between our calculated time and midnight Saturday
7. We then fast forward to Monday morning at Midnight
8. We then add the difference we got on step 6
9. If we're adding 10 days we're crossing two weekends so we need to add an extra 48 hours

Hopefully this is educational for you and introduces you to the power of PHP's DateTime capabilities.

Comment: when I call addRollover('2014-03-26 00:00:00','daily') I get '2014-04-07 00:00:00', but I expect '2014-04-08 00:00:00' (10 days). Any idea why?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Try about ten more and let me know if you find any other inconsistencies. That will help debug this.

Comment: I bet it is because it spans multiple weeknds.

Comment: See if my updated answer works as you would expect. I get 2014-04-09 00:00:00 which is what I expect.

Comment: 03-26 gives the correct answer now (04-09) but '2014-03-25 00:00:00' gives 04-04 when 04-08 is expected: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e119ea693cd47652c89822e7c8208b08378fa80a

Comment: We're close. The double weekends is more complex then I thought. I won't be able to revisit this again until tomorrow but if you haven't sorted it out by then I'll see if I can work that out.

Comment: also, thanks for the detailed explanation. PHP has a lot of hidden power in their date/time manipulation, but sometimes the documentation is a bit opaque.

Comment: small update - for case: "15m" construct should be "PT2H30M", not "P2H30M".